# Alternate of Azure VPN

Tags: azure

I have two vms both in different vNets but in same datacenter. I need to copy some files from vm1 to vm2 however I don't want to use azure vpn connection.

Is there any other alternative to do so ?

Answer (score 0):

How about using Azure Storage Account https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-create-storage-account/

You can access a storage account from both the VM, if I'm not wrong.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use **Azure File Storage**
   https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/storage/files/
   https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files/
   Basically, you'll use `net use` or `mount -t cifs`.
2. Share a folder from VM2 and copy files over SMB by calling the Public IP address:
   `net use z: \\public_ip_addr_of_VM2\share`
   Make sure you open 445/TCP on both VMs first. Use a Network Security Group (NSG) to restrict access to that port.
3. If your VMs are in different Virtual Networks (which most probably is why you're asking this in the first place) you could use VNET peering:
   https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-create-vnetpeering-arm-portal/

   > VNet Peering is a mechanism to connect two Virtual Networks in the same region through the Azure backbone network. Once peered, the two Virtual Networks will appear like a single Virtual Network for all connectivity purposes.
   >   [image: VNET Peering]

   Copy files over SMB. Careful with firewalls and 445/TCP.